# Why does Rust compiler not perform tail call for diverging functions even when unwinding is disabled?

Tags: rust

Intuitively, since diverging functions in Rust do not return, the compiler can optimize the function calls to diverging functions into tail calls.

One [known caveat](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/diverging-function-call-optimization/15247) is that although diverging functions cannot return from the normal execution flow, they still can return from unwinding the stack due to a panic until getting caught by `std::panic::catch_unwind`.

However, if we set `panic=abort` in `Cargo.toml` to disable unwinding, diverging functions will faithfully diverge, and thus should open up the opportunity to perform tail calls to these functions. Unfortunately, Rust compiler (`rustc 1.72.0-nightly (065a1f5df 2023-06-21)`) currently does not perform such tail call optimization.

##### Evidence

The `dummy()` function below calls a diverging function `dead()`. In the ideal case, after `dummy()` finishes executing its body, it should *clean up its stack frame* and perform a jump to `dead()`.

```rust
#[inline(never)]
fn dead() -> ! { loop {} }

#[inline(never)]
fn dummy() -> ! {
    let i = 0;
    unsafe { std::ptr::read_volatile(&i); }
    dead()
}

fn main() { dummy() }
```

However, even if we compile the function in `--release` mode with `panic=abort`, the tail call optimization is not performed, as can be seen in the disassembly below:

```
00000000000085c0 <diverge::dummy::h304a1bb7bcfb3a1b>:
    85c0: 50                            pushq   %rax
    85c1: c7 44 24 04 00 00 00 00       movl    $0x0, 0x4(%rsp)
    85c9: 8b 44 24 04                   movl    0x4(%rsp), %eax
    85cd: e8 de ff ff ff                callq   0x85b0 <diverge::dead::h74c97e16d77999e8>
    85d2: 0f 0b                         ud2
    85d4: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
    85de: 66 90                         nop
```

`dummy()` still keeps its stack frame and performs a `callq` to `dead()` rather than a `jmpq`.

##### Why It Matters

Rust is gaining popularity in embedded world because of its (mostly) compile time enforced memory safety. Embedded systems have small RAM, thus it matters to have smaller stack usage. A typical structure of an embedded task looks like below:

```rust
fn task_entry() -> ! {
    // Some initialization code.
    // Perhaps uses quite some space in the stack.

    // We are ready, run the periodical task.
    run();
}

fn run() -> ! {}
```

If `run()` is not optimized as a tail call, the stack will end up with containing useless data at the bottom which are only used during initialization but stay there throughout the rest of the lifetime.

I am curious if the proposed optimization is impossible because some other corner case prevents it from working, or it is a missed optimization opportunity.

Comment: I feel like there's not going to be one conclusive, objective answer to "why" this optimization isn't being performed (unless a bunch of compiler contributors are going to chime in here), though I would guess that the reasons are similar to [those for the general case](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605150233/https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-April/003557.html). It might be of interest that there is [a new RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3407) proposing explicit tail call syntax.

Comment: In this case `dead` doesn't even use any stack, so applying TCO doesn't really make sense? Perhaps there is some sort of heuristic.

Comment: By the way, if this is absolutely critical and doesn't need to be particularly portable (supported archs are x86[-64], ARM, AArch64, and RISC-V), you can use Rust's [inline assembly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html). Then you can replace the call to `dummy` with `unsafe { asm! { "jmp {dead}", dead = sym dead, options(noreturn), } }` (at least for your dummy example case).

Comment: Oh, and with a `#[cfg(panic = "abort")]` slapped on there for safety.